# What is the order normally used in the "low quality posts" tab of the review page?

Tags: support, review

When I disable the random order, how are the posts in the "low quality posts" tab of the review page ordered?

Without any option selected, what I see is something similar to this:

[image: screenshot]

When I select "Lowest Score First," what I see is something similar to this:

[image: screenshot]

What is the default ordering for that tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are ordered randomly. If you refresh the page you'll see a different set of posts to review.